# Selenium webdriver tests stop running after some time of execution

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I have been trying to run selenium tests on IE 11 and Chrome. In both the cases, the tests just stop running after 25 odd tests (total 350 TCs).

Configuration: Windows 10 pro / Tried both 32/64 bit IE driver / Selenium 3.4.0

Complete logs here: https://www.scribd.com/document/356096163/Logs

I am getting no error, it seems like driver just freezes, and after couple of minutes all the rest of TCs get skipped.

Note: I have done all the required configurations for IE driver, that were needed.

Comment: Nobody will study megabytes of your logs. Please, extract the ones that show your problem as well as create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @IvanPronin : I know, its bad on my part. But havent' been able to pin down any problem yet. Logs also dont have any error related to that. Just attached the whole thing, thinking i must have must a minute thing maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is in absent element.
At the bottom of the logs I found (could not copy-paste log from the site you've specified)

> > org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException

The exception is thrown when using `FluentWait.until` method - so, the method didn't find element with `id=sortable`.
The exception stops other tests from going since it's not caught.
Wrap it into `try-catch` block

Comment: it didnt' help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your logs it seems the main reason why `Selenium webdriver tests stop running after some time of execution` is because at some point of time your script is facing an exception as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

That is because, while polling the `HttpClientConnection`, a status of  **Connection released** was detected with **total kept alive: 0**, hence the Expected Conditions which was set to `visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath")` was throwing:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException
```

As the  **`ExpectedConditions`** which was part of the **`WebDriverWait`** failed, so your next step with some action on the desired element also **`FAILED`** but with:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

### Solution:

A solution to your issue may to configure the `http-outgoing` connection to remain `keep alive` for a certain period of time so Selenium can perform it's configured actions.

Comment: can you please help me with where can i set the value for http-outgoing to keep alive?